# Error while passing an object by reference to another class' constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I have two classes one of them has an object of another class as a data member and it's constructor accepts the class object to initialize the data member object.

```
class x{

public:
    x(int a, int b)
     { cout << a << b;}
  };

class y{

 x temp;

 y(x& o){ this-> temp = o;}
 };
```

But compiler shows an error in y::y(x&): no matching function to call x::x()

I am using codeblocks 16.01

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have defined the constructor:

```
x(int a, int b)
```

in `x`. This means that the compiler will no longer define any constructors for you, this includes the `x()` constructor. So you can **only** construct `x` with `x(int, int)`. Here in your code:

```
 x temp;
 y(x& o) { // < No initializer list
```

You attempt to default construct `x`, but `x` has no default constructor! Either define one, or construct `x` in the initializer list with the constructor you have provided.

For example:

```
y(x& o) : x(0, 0) {
```

But you will create your object then you will use the implicitly defined `copy-assignment` operator to assign it, which is a bit of a waste of time. You can actually solve all these problems by using the `copy-constructor`:

```
 class x{
    ...
    x(const x &copy) { // Define a copy constructor or just use 
                       // the implicitly defined one.
```

Then in `y`, just use it in `y`'s initializater list:

```
 x temp;
 y(x& o) : temp(o) {}
```

Comment: Both copy construction and copy-assignment are defined by the compiler implicitly in such simple cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
y(x& o){ this-> temp = o; }
```

is not very C++ idiomatic.

I. As a rule, you should avoid requiring more access rights than needed. Here, you're likely to not mutate the construction argument, so you don't need to pass it by a `mutable reference`:

```
y(x const &o);
```

II. Member initialization is done very differently in C++:

```
y(x const &o): temp(o) {}
```

When you write

```
y(x const &o) { temp = o; } // please avoid writing `this->'
```

then what happens is: first, `temp` is constructed and default-initialized (prior to the opening brace); then, inside the braces, `temp` is already a valid object, so what follows is a copy-assignment. In your case, `x` is not default-constructible, so compilation fails.